# Как сохранить данные в TXT файл [SWIFT]?

Tags: swift

Есть некоторые данные, которые я сохраняю, когда человек вписывает свое имя и фамилию в Text Field. Как я могу эти данные сохранять в .txt файл?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift 3.0

```
let file = "file.txt" //this is the file. we will write to and read from it

let text = "some text" //just a text

if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {

    let path = dir.appendingPathComponent(file)

    //writing
    do {
        try text.write(to: path, atomically: false, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    }
    catch {/* error handling here */}

    //reading
    do {
        let text2 = try String(contentsOf: path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    }
    catch {/* error handling here */}
}
```

для других свифтов найдешь код здесь: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24097826/read-and-write-data-from-text-file

Comment: Использую Swift 3.0, но этот способ не записывает данные. Открываю после загрузки файл и там пусто

Comment: пройди по линке и попробуй другие способа описанные там)